# Port 22: operation timed out error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

While running my stored AMI in amazon AWS, after I type

```
ssh -i "Test123.pem" root@ec2-54-200-131-117.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I got an error

```
ssh: connect to host ec2-54-200-131-117.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

If I start a new instance using UBUNTU AMI it is working, but if I start my stored AMI instance it says the above error.

My stored AMI was built over basic Ubuntu AMI and it is public
AMI id : ami-d119deb1

Please help me

Comment: Is port 22 open in the security group for the instance that you are unable to connect to? Also look at the solutions on this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are SSH'ing using root user which you cannot do in Linux ubuntu instance.

Use below command it will work.

```
ssh -i "Test123.pem" ubuntu@ec2-54-200-131-117.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```